# Does Hazelcast trigger the onRemoved listener for expired cache values?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I've been trying to integrate Hazelcast into my application but am running into a behaviour I had not anticipated with the onExpired vs onRemoved listener.

Ideally, I would like to execute some code whenever a value is removed from my cache.  I configured an Expiry policy on the cache, and am expecting that my onRemoved listener will follow after my cache value expires, but it does not seem to be the case.

Does Hazelcast call the onRemoved listener after when it removes an expired value from the cache, or only on an explicit `cache.remove()` call?

My configuration is:

```
            hazelcastInstance = HazelcastInstanceFactory.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(getHazelcastConfig());

            // Add cache used by adams
            CacheSimpleConfig cacheSimpleConfig = new CacheSimpleConfig()
                    .setName(CACHE_NAME)
                    .setKeyType(UserRolesCacheKey.class.getName())
                    .setValueType((new String[0]).getClass().getName())
                    .setReadThrough(true)
                    .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
                    .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                            .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                            .setSize(1000)
                            .setMaximumSizePolicy(EvictionConfig.MaxSizePolicy.ENTRY_COUNT))
                    .setExpiryPolicyFactoryConfig(
                            new ExpiryPolicyFactoryConfig(
                                    new TimedExpiryPolicyFactoryConfig(ACCESSED,
                                            new DurationConfig(
                                                    120,
                                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS))));

            hazelcastInstance.getConfig().addCacheConfig(cacheSimpleConfig);

            ICache<UserRolesCacheKey, String[]> userRolesCache = hazelcastInstance.getCacheManager().getCache(CACHE_NAME);

            userRolesCache.registerCacheEntryListener(new MutableCacheEntryListenerConfiguration<>(
                            new UserRolesCacheListenerFactory(), null, false, false));

        }
    }
}
```

My Listener is fairly simple:

```
public class UserRolesCacheListenerFactory implements Factory<CacheEntryListener<UserRolesCacheKey, String[]>> {

    @Override
    public CacheEntryListener create() {
        return new UserRolesCacheEntryListener();
    }

}
```

And:

```
public class UserRolesCacheEntryListener implements CacheEntryRemovedListener<UserRolesCacheKey, String[]>{
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRolesCacheEntryListener.class);


    @Override
    public void onRemoved(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends UserRolesCacheKey, ? extends String[]>> cacheEntryEvents) throws CacheEntryListenerException {
        cacheEntryEvents.forEach(this::deleteDBData);
    }
```

I would expect that sometime after 120s my `onRemoved` method would be called by Hazelcast as it removes the expired value from the cache, but it never seems to be.

Is this expected behaviour?  Is something missing in my cache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

According to the JCache specification, section 8.4, the `REMOVED` event is only for explicit operations.

Listening for `EXPIRED` event will be better but still not ideal.

Note the wording in the specification and the code [here](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/cache/event/CacheEntryExpiredListener.java#L31). `EXPIRED` events are implementation dependent  -- a caching provider is allowed to never notice the data has expired, never remove it, and so never generate the event.

Hazelcast does notice [see here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#jcache-eviction), but this makes the timely appearance of the event you need dependent on the implementation.

Comment: So I've read through that doc already, and indeed it indicates that but under the JCache implementation heading only.  So I'm not sure if that is only when Hazelcast is used as a JCache implementation, or even if it is used natively without JCache APIs.  I cannot seem to find any documentation or reference which indicates if the removal of an expired value triggers the removed listener.

Comment: You could raise an issue https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/issues to get the spec clarified ?